# Timer not working when using readline-sync (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, timer

I am making a game that keeps track of the time you take to complete the game, however i realised that the timer does not continue when i am asking for input.I tried to wait 10 seconds before typing a input but after i input a value the time is 00:00.Must i create a separate file for the timer or is there a possible way for the timer to run.Please help thanks!

```
var readline = require('readline-sync');
seconds = 0;
minute = 0;

timer = setInterval(() => {

    if (seconds == 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minute++;
    }
    
    seconds++;

}, 1000);

var input = readline.question('Input:');

clearInterval(timer);

//String to show time
if (minute < 10 && seconds < 10)
time = '0' + minute + ':0' + seconds;
else if (minute < 10 && seconds >= 10)
time = '0' + minute + ':' + seconds;
else if (minute >= 10 && seconds < 10)
time = minute + ':0' + seconds;
else 
time = minute + ':' + seconds;

console.log(time);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier just to create a Date object with `new Date()` and substract it from another Date created after the user Input.

```
var dateStart = new Date();
var input = readline.question('Input:');
var difference = new Date() - dateStart(); // time elapsed in milliseconds
```

For more complex cases I'd recommend looking up the libraries moment.js or date-fns.